# How can I concatenate two C++ maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, merge, insert, concatenation

How can I concatenate the following two maps?

```
map<string, map<string,string>> map1;
map<string, map<string,string>> map2;
```

I just want to add `map2` to `map1` and keep all elements already in `map1`, i.e., add `map2` at the end of `map1`. I've tried `map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end())`, but it does not work since it overwrites old elements in `map1`.

Comment: "it does not work" - it _does_ work. That's how std::map is defined: a collection of Key-Value pairs, sorted by the unique keys.

Comment: And do you care to keep all the elements in `map2` too?

Comment: why would I do that if I've already added those elements to map1?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question contradicts with the concept of a map.  If you insert a value in a map, you expect it to be at 'the proper place', depending on it's key.  This implies there is only one entry for each key.

Instead, you could use a `vector< pair< mymap::key, myamap::value > >` and fill it with the entries of the first resp. the second map.

```
map< string, int > map1, map2;
... fill the maps
vector< pair<string, int> > concatted;
concatted.insert( map1.begin(), map1.end() );
concatted.insert( map2.begin(), map2.end() );
```

Comment: But doesn't this create two different map i.e. a list containing map[0], map[1]... All I want to do is append maps to another map in a for loop.

Comment: @Niklas: that's the point: you cannot append two maps.  You can create the 'union', but double entries will get lost.

Comment: The `insert()` method requires a `positon` where to insert the range as the first parameter:
`... concatted.insert( concatted.begin(), map1.begin(), map1.end() ); ... `

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to merge them but in case of collisions keep the elements from map1, then just reverse the maps:

```
std::swap(map1, map2);
map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());
```

This of course assumes that after the merge, you're only interested in the result and lo longer in the old collections.

Answer (score 4):

map<> can contain only one value for one key. try using [multimap<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a simple for-loop: (althrough i like to use stl algorithms where plausible):

```
for(std::map<...>::const_iterator it = map2.begin(), it_end = map2.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
   map1.insert(*it);
```

Any element whose key already is in map1 *won't* be overwritten as `map::insert` doesn't overwrite.

Comment: so it conceptually 'overwrites' the entries in `map2`.  Back at sqr 1?

Comment: Que? It does not modify map2 in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If a map is not too big, do the opposite:

```
map2.insert(map1.begin(), map1.end());
map1 = map2;
```

This will overwrite duplicate values in `map2`, but will keep the ones in `map1` (I understand this is what you wanted).

Comment: Actually, why does insert with a range replaces and insert with one element doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) provides a [`merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) member function, so you can simply call `map1.merge(map2);`. Please note, that a map is sorted by its keys, so that elements will not necessarily be appended at the end. Also, because the keys in a map are unique, not all elements from `map2` might be inserted into `map1`. Full example:

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> map1{
        {"a", {{"b", "b"}}}, {"b", {{"c", "c"}}}
    };

    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> map2{
        {"b", {{"x", "x"}}}, {"c", {{"y", "y"}}}
    };

    map1.merge(map2);  // C++17

    std::cout << "map1:" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &kv : map1)
        std::cout << kv.first << ": " << kv.second.begin()->first << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "map2:" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &kv : map2)
        std::cout << kv.first << ": " << kv.second.begin()->first << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> map1:
>   a: b
>   b: c
>   c: y
>
> map2:
>   b: x

As you can see, `merge()` does not overwrite existing elements in the target map `map1` when keys overlap. If you want to to give priority to elements from `map2`, then you have to call `map2.merge(map1);`. As you can also see, `merge()` moves entries over from the source map. Elements that cannot be merged remain in `map2`.

[Code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4becccd72b9fc1c9)